# How to Return Different data types in Abstract class of java

Tags: java, abstract-class

I am New in java and I am learning Abstraction class but I have stuck on a place.

I want to return Different data types to `abstract class Bank` but I can't do that .I did refer [Different return types of abstract method in java without casting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15037880/different-return-types-of-abstract-method-in-java-without-casting)  this question because i have less experience in java therefore i did't understand that link's solution.Please anyone help me to solve the issue

**code**

```
abstract class Bank{
    abstract int rateOfInterest();
}

class Icici extends Bank{
    int rateOfInterest(){
        return 8;
    }
}

class Sbi extends Bank{
    int rateOfInterest(){
        return 7;
    }
}


class Union extends Bank{
    float rateOfInterest(){
        return 9.5;
    }
}


class Interest {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Bank uni = new Union();
        System.out.println("The rate of interest of UNION Bank is "+uni.rateOfInterest());
    }
}
```

**Error**

> test.java:18: error: Union is not abstract and does not override abstract method rateOfInterest() in Bank
>
> class Union extends Bank{
>   ^
>   test.java:19: error: rateOfInterest() in Union cannot override rateOfInterest() in Bank
>
> float rateOfInterest(){
>                 ^
>     return type float is not compatible with int
>
> test.java:20: error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to float
>                   return 9.5;
>                          ^
>   3 errors

**Expected Output**

```
The rate of interest of UNION Bank is 9.5
```

Comment: Change all your `rateOfInterest` to return `BigDecimal`

Answer (score 2):

You mixed/confused with types.

Your parent methods return type is `int` and you are giving it as `float` in children. That won't work.

Change it to same data type everywhere.

Apart from that, use `double` for rate of interest instead of floating. That is the suitable data type for rate of interest.

```
abstract class Bank{
    abstract double rateOfInterest();
}

class Icici extends Bank{
    double rateOfInterest(){
        return 8;
    }
}

class Sbi extends Bank{
    double rateOfInterest(){
        return 7;
    }
}


class Union extends Bank{
    double rateOfInterest(){
        return 9.5;
    }
}


class Interest {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Bank uni = new Union();
        System.out.println("The rate of interest of UNION Bank is "+uni.rateOfInterest());
    }
}
```

Again double also have floating point and  choose the best data type from the discussion here [What is the best data type to use for money in Java app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148684/what-is-the-best-data-type-to-use-for-money-in-java-app)

Comment: thanks for answer  but if my data type is different in different childs then how to return that ?

Comment: @sachindubey Just convert it before returning.

Comment: can we do it using generics ?

Comment: even `double` is not suitable to caculate money since it sufferes the same *fixed length aproximation* problem as `float`. Both cannot represent `0.1` since this is a *endless fraction* in binary.

Comment: @ꜱᴜʀᴇꜱʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ: You can't. The compiler can't distinguish methods by return type so you have to distinguish them by name. If appropriate, one of your methods could call the other one internally.

Comment: @sachindubey *genecics* work for *object types*, but you calculate with *primitives*

Comment: @TimothyTruckle Agreed. I know there is alot of discussion going on for the same https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148684/what-is-the-best-data-type-to-use-for-money-in-java-app

Comment: @userunknown so you are saying, return type is not a part of method signature ?

Comment: @ꜱᴜʀᴇꜱʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ No, he didn't.

Comment: Ahh sorry. My bad. Confused.

Comment: I would need to research the meaning of the word "signature" to answer that, but without research I can tell you, that you can't overload a method by return type while you can do it with parameter type. The roI in Union is in conflict about the return type with the declaration of Bank. It's what the compiler is trying to tell you.

Answer (score 0):

In you Bank class the rateOfInterest() returns int value and your Union rateOfInterest() return float value.

When your implementing abstract method in child classes, you return type should be higher type, should not be lower type.

To fix that either you can change the return type to float from int, like shown below

```
abstract float rateOfInterest();
```

Otherwise change the return type as int from float in you Union class, like shown below

```
int rateOfInterest(){
        return 9;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Even this solution also can help you. As here as i mention double is higher type, it stores int, float  values as per you expected.

```
abstract class Bank{
    abstract Double rateOfInterest();
}

class Icici extends Bank{
    Double rateOfInterest(){
        return 8d;
    }
}

class Sbi extends Bank{
    Double rateOfInterest(){
        return 7d;
    }
}


class Union extends Bank{
    Double rateOfInterest(){
        return 9.5;
    }
}


class Interest {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Bank uni = new Union();
        System.out.println("The rate of interest of UNION Bank is "+uni.rateOfInterest());
    }
}
```

you can cast required type from Double.

Answer (score 0):

Beside the actual problem your example revales a possible vilolation of the *information hiding* principle and the *feature envy* code smell.

having a `Bank` implementer exposing its *interest rate* might lead to code where you put calculations with that property into a class *using* a bank:

```
int deposit = 1000;
Bank someBank = new Sbi();
deposit += deposit * someBank.rateOfInterest();
```

In real life your bank does not allow you to calculate your accounts deposit yourself. You rather have your bank doing that in regular time periods and the calculation should be inside the bank.

You need a different interface:

```
interface Bank {
   void subLoanInterest();
   void addSavingsInterest();
   void printDeposit(PrintStream out);
}


Bank someBank = new Sbi(1000); // initial value
someBank.addSavingsInterest();
someBank.printDeposit(System.out);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want ***any*** data type

```
class Bank<T>{
T rateOfInterest();
}
```

T means it will accept and return whatever data type you instantiate it with.